# Style <hr> element to fit between two spans

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS for an `<hr />` element:

```
.question-line-row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin: 0 0 25pt;
}
.true-and-false-line{
    border: dashed #333;
    border-width: 0 0 1pt;
    flex: 1 0 0;
}
.justify-trueandfalse{
    border: solid #333;
    border-width: 0 0 1pt;
    margin-top: 15pt;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div class="question-line-row">
    <span style="text-align: justify" ng-style="{'font-size' : statementSize}">
            {{statement}}
    </span>
    <hr class="true-and-false-line" />
    <span style="text-align: justify" ng-style="{'font-size' : statementSize}">(&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;)</span>
</div>
<hr class="justify-trueandfalse" ng-show="verify" />
```

This is, however what is in the output:
[image: <hr> element output]

How can I make the dashed `<hr />` line to be at the same level of the two sorrounding `<span></span>`'s?

Comment: The `<hr>` tag has no closing slash. Also `<hr>` represents a pargraph level thematic break so your usage is incorrect. You aren't to use it as a styling element.

Comment: I'm confused. The dashed <hr> **is** in between the two spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these code:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="question-line-row">
    <span>Test Text</span>
    <hr class="true-and-false-line" />
    <span>test text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.question-line-row{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}
.true-and-false-line{
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  flex: 1;
}
span{
  margin: 5px;
}
```